# Flutter Firebase documents are randomly ordered

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I made a simple chat app using Flutter. My app is functioning perfectly fine (getting and dumping data into firebase) but once my messages get into my database, they are randomly ordered resulting in my msgs getting displayed in a random order.

I have tried reversing the SnapshotQueue in my Flutter code but that did not help...

Comment: Please edit the question to describe in more detail what's not working the way you expect, including your code.  We should be able to duplicate what you observe using the details you provide.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to attach document names to your documents before uploading them.
I think you are experiencing this issue because your documents are being given Auto Ids.

Try using the current timestamp as the document name. this will help arrange documents in order according to time uploaded.

`Firestore.instance.collection(CollectionName).document(Timestamp.now()).setData(messageMap);`

i hope this is what you need. if not. Please share your code that uploads the message to database.

Comment: Pretty good info. However, you're better off storing timestamp data in a child field so it can be used for ordering as well as querying. If you store it as a documentId, it will limit it's use. Let Firestore create documentId's and enforce ordering with .order clauses on the document fields.

Comment: Yeah sure. your right that's the best approach. i personally just prefer less code. because with that, i don't have to do any ordering but can do all the sorting i want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a field like  `datePublished = DateTime.now()` to each message document as
   it gets created to
   store the timestamp of when the message was created
2. Then you can use datePublished field to order your documents of your QuerySnapshot like this:

   `QuerySnapshot snapshot = await collection.orderBy('datePublished', descending: true).get();`

   now your messages are arranged in chronological order from the latest
   to earliest.